# how to move two Devex gridview columns together?

Tags: c#, devexpress

i am using devex gridview with c#, what i want is when i drag column to change its order, other column should to be moved next or before my moved column i used mouse up event and column position changed event i get a stack over flow exception 
the could used is :

```
 int index1 = gridView1.Columns["mail2"].VisibleIndex;
m_Mail1selection.CheckMarkColumn.VisibleIndex = index1;
int index2 = gridView1.Columns["mail1"].VisibleIndex;
m_Mail2selection.CheckMarkColumn.VisibleIndex = index2;
```

any one know how to achieve that, the first columns is for mail address and the second is a Checkedit to mark the email is going to be sent or not and the ssame thing for mail2

thanks in advance to any help

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ColumnPositionChanged event, however you need to ensure you use conditions. The problem you have is you are setting the VisibleIndex regardless if you need to or not, as you keep changing the position of the column the event keeps firing and therefore puts the event into a eternal loop (which what a StackOverflow is)

Try something like this

```
    private void gridView1_ColumnPositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((colMail1Check.VisibleIndex - colMail1.VisibleIndex) != 1)
        {
            colMail1Check.VisibleIndex = colMail1.VisibleIndex + 1;
        }
        if ((colMail2Check.VisibleIndex - colMail2.VisibleIndex) != 1)
        {
            colMail2Check.VisibleIndex = colMail2.VisibleIndex + 1;
        }
    }
```

What this will do is check if the Check column is next to its "main" column and if not adjust the VisibleIndex to be next to the main column. This will also handle if someone drags the column in between the two columns (ie, you drag the Mail2 column in between the Mail1 and Mail1Check columns, as the Mail2Check will be moved next to Mail2 and Mail1Check will be moved beside the Mail1 again, ensuring it is always beside the column.

Hope this helps

Comment: also i used boolean variable to make sure that the grid have done loading.